# Project Euler #50 in Java(Solution not working)

Tags: java, algorithm, debugging

My result is wrong, but I can't find bugs.

**Problem Description:**

> The prime 41, can be written as the sum of six consecutive primes:41 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13. This is the longest sum of consecutive primes that adds to a prime below one-hundred. The longest sum of consecutive primes below one-thousand that adds to a prime, contains 21 terms, and is equal to 953. Which prime, below one-million, can be written as the sum of the most consecutive primes?

**My idea:**

> 1. Starting from the first prime 2, compute the longest sum of consecutive primes that adds to a **number** below 1 million.
> 2. Count down from the longest, for each certain length, compute the sum of seri start from 2, then compute the sum of seri start from the second prime...
> 3. Stop when a sum is a prime.

**My Code:**

```
public class Prob50 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long sum=0;
    int count=0;
    for(int i = 2; ; i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            if((sum+=i)>1000000){
                sum-=i;
                break;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    int jump=0;
    boolean isOver= false;
    boolean isAns= false;
    for(;count>0;count--){
        jump=0;

        for(;;){
            int tempj=jump;
            int tempc=count;
            sum=0;
            for(int i = 2;tempc>0 ; i++){

                if(isPrime(i)&&tempj>0){
                    tempj--;
                    continue;
                }

                if(isPrime(i)){
                    tempc--;
                    if((sum+=i)>1000000){
                        sum-=i;
                        isOver=true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(isPrime(sum)){
                isAns=true;
                break;
            }
            if(isOver){
                break;
            }
            jump++;
        }

        if(isAns){
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(sum+" "+count);
}

private static boolean isPrime(long n){
    for(int i = 2 ; i <= Math.sqrt(n) ; i++){
        if(n%i==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

**My result:**

> 958577 536

The answer is 997651 and the count is supposed to be 543.

Comment: So what's the question, exactly?

Comment: @Todd the result is wrong.

Comment: It seems you could solve this by adding a couple lines of code to your very first loop, and throw away all the remaining complicated stuff you're doing in that big second loop. Rather than find the bug in overly complicated code, find a much simpler algorithm.

Comment: @hatchet, the first loop used to get the maximum length of prime seri, I don't know how can you solve it by adding few lines.

Comment: You can just combine step 1 and 2, find sum and check for its primality at the same time :)

Comment: Every time you find a new prime, and add it to the sum, check if the new sum is prime (and not over 1,000,000). If it is, remember it, and the current count as the best answer found so far. When you exceed 1,000,000 then use the remembered count and sum as your answer.

Comment: @hatchet,yeah, you can do that. In your way, first I need find the sum of two prime:(2,3),(3,5),(5,7)...then find the sum of three primes:(2,3,5),(3,5,7)...that I think take more computation.

Comment: No, you misunderstood hatchet, for your very first loop, just add one simple line `if(isPrime(sum) && sum < 1000000) answer = sum;`. That's it, and you can remove the rest of your algo.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. The consecutive primes won't necessarily start with 2? It could start with 13 for example?

Comment: @PhamTrung It actually can't give us the right answer. Let's assume that the answer seri is (5,7,11), how am I suppose to get that.

Comment: Oh, I see, you are right :)

Comment: Why aren't you using the sieve of Eratosthenes to build a table of primes instead of doing trial division to test whether a number is prime?

Comment: @DavidConrad I searched Sieve of Eratosthenes, it is good idea. I will update the code later, but what is the bug of this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, just need to add:

```
isOver= false;
```

between `isOver= false;` and `for(;;){`.